# jquery $.getJSON callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-callback

I am running the following bit of code, to get a JSON file from my server,

```
$.getJSON('json/' + $(e.currentTarget).data("collectionjson") + '.json', function(data){
    console.log(data)           
});
```

`$(e.currentTarget).data("collectionjson")` = backbonerscollection

So the get request for the json is getting sent to `json/backbonerscollection.json` and I am getting `200 OK` response from the server, so why is the console.log not getting fired in the callback?

The full portion of the javascript looks like this,

```
collections: {

            makeSelection: function(e) {
                var that = this;
                $(".collection.selected").toggleClass("selected");
                //console.log($(e.currentTarget).data());
                $(e.currentTarget).addClass("selected");
                //Fire a GET request for the chosen collections data
                $.getJSON('json/' + $(e.currentTarget).data("collectionjson") + '.json', function(data){
                    console.log(data);


                });
            }

        }
```

Comment: Can u console `'json/' + $(e.currentTarget).data("collectionjson") + '.json'` and see whether its the correct URL to the json file?. You can simply double check this by using a jquery-ajax call to the same...

Comment: Bring up the Developer Tools for your browser and check the network tab – what response are you seeing for this AJAX request?

Comment: the url must be correct, otherwise I would get a 404 error not found, rather than a 200 OK

Comment: @Backboner Just because the url is wrong doesn't mean it would necessarily go to a 404. What does your JSON look like? my guess is it is invalid.